# MySQL - accent insensitive search with polish characters - UTF8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

I found a lot of answers about collation and accent insensitive search, read like 1000 posts and articles about this problem, but did not find the answer.

Does anybody know how to force MySQL to search accent insensitive with ALL polish characters? Maybe anybody got a compiled collation file for that (Debian)?

Please note, that:

- Setting collation to `utf8_general_ci` does not help. It does not support `Ł` properly. But it does ruin search order.
- Setting collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` does not help. Same as above.
- Editing collation files is not possible because it is multibyte encoding. And multibyte charsets have to be compiled.
- Replacing all unsupported letters with supported ones is not a solution.

I really don't understand why MySQL crew doesn't treat this as a bug. It's obvious, that it is, and it has been for ages. Since 4. xx they did correct `Ś` letter... so why not `Ł` ?!

I found some references to [This MySQL functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation-unicode-uca.html), but no information on how to use it. I don't really understand what is being written there and if it can help me.

Tests:

```
mysql> show full columns from test;
+-------+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field | Type         | Collation      | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| str   | varchar(255) | utf8_polish_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+

mysql> insert into test values('Łomża');
```

...

```
mysql> select str from test where str like '%Łomża%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
str: Łomża

mysql> select str from test where str like '%Łomza%'\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)

--

mysql> select str from test where str like '%Łomza%' collate utf8_general_ci\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
str: Łomża

mysql> select str from test where str like '%Lomza%' collate utf8_general_ci\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)

--

mysql> select str from test where str like '%Łomza%' collate utf8_unicode_ci\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
str: Łomża

mysql> select str from test where str like '%Lomza%' collate utf8_unicode_ci\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I don't understand, we use MySQL to do search even with strong 4-byte chinese ideograms, why Ł is a problem?

Comment: Ask MySQL devs. And they don't consider it as a bug! Was reported like 100000 times for past 5 years and the official answer was that it is not a bug. Please check attached examples. I've edited question.

Comment: I cannot help you as I have not polish console. You worked with select str from test where str like '%Łomża%'\G; why you search with select str from test where str like '%Łomza%'\G, that logically returns an empty set? I inserted str as utf8_general_ci, the like operator seems work via PHP/PDO/MySQL.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. With those tests I wanted to show that collate does not work only for `Ł` letter. When I search for `ż`, it works fine with `ż` as well as `z`. But with `Ł` it does not. And about the polish console ... it is german server with english debian :)

Comment: Would you update your question with a link to the reported bug regarding "Ł" in MySQL? That seems to be a critical detail that readers would need to understand, and of course they would have to evaluate whether it is indeed a problem on the MySQL side.

Comment: Re the above question: The link to the reported bug regarding "Ł" in MySQL is https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9604 but it was properly closed as "not a bug".

Comment: yeah... I know... how wasn't it a bug? of course it was

Answer (score 5):

I just started to using MySql and the answer for 'Polish' problem is to collate `utf8_unicode_520_ci` (or `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`) where `l=ł=L=Ł` - same for other, not only Polish, accents.

No char conversion, no ascii column, no nothing… After years of searching for ł/Ł sollution in Sqlite.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making another column for searching in your database, such as 'str_search'.  When inserting strings to 'str_search' in your database, make and use a function in PHP like so:

```
 function convertPolishChars($phrase)
 {
    $phrase = str_replace("ą", "a", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ą", "A", $phrase);

    $phrase = str_replace("ć", "c", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ć", "C", $phrase);

    $phrase = str_replace("ę", "e", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ę", "E", $phrase);

    $phrase = str_replace("ł", "l", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ł", "L", $phrase);

    $phrase = str_replace("ń", "n", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ń", "N", $phrase);

    $phrase = str_replace("ó", "o", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ó", "O", $phrase);

    $phrase = str_replace("ś", "s", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ś", "S", $phrase);

    $phrase = str_replace("ź", "z", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ź", "Z", $phrase);

    $phrase = str_replace("ż", "z", $phrase);
    $phrase = str_replace("Ż", "Z", $phrase);

    return $phrase;
 }

"INSERT INTO test (str, str_search) VALUES ('Łomża', '" . convertPolishChars('Łomża') . "')"
```

and when writing a SQL query, write something like:

```
"SELECT str FROM test WHERE str_search like '%" . convertPolishChars('Łomża') . "%'"
```

This approach will execute your query string much faster, rather than doing any conversions in the SQL statement.

Make sure to Index your 'str_search' column.

For larger databases, I recommend **FULLTEXT** searches with **MATCH AGAINST**.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html